# Covariance matrix estimation

Tags: estimation, covariance, bessel-functions

I will talk about the estimation of an unknown covariance matrix from a sample (of N points) when:

- The mean vector (MV) is known.
- The mean vector is unknown.

In the case of when the mean vector is known, the estimation of the covariance matrix is given by the following equation:(the SCM is = the "Sample Covariance Matrix" is:)
$$\frac1N \sum_{i=1}^N (x_i - \bar x)(x_i - \bar x)^T$$

In the case of when the mean vector is unknown, the covariance matrix should be estimated by the following equation: (SCM = Sample Covariance Matrix)
$$\frac1{N+1} \sum_{i=1}^N (x_i - \bar x)(x_i - \bar x)^T$$

**In that case, there are N degrees of freedom in a sample of N points, and simultaneous estimation of mean and covariance means one degree of freedom goes to the sample mean and the remaining N-1 degrees of freedom (the residuals) go to the sample covariance.**

**In other terms, when the mean vector is unknown, the Bessel's correction is applied to the estimated covariance matrix: multiplying (1/N) by (N/N-1) in order to get the fraction (1/N-1). So the fraction (n/n-1) is called "Bessel's correction".**

Unfortunately I didn't understand the above bolded statements. Kindly can someone explain to me in details how to get the N degrees of freedom and what is the motivation of multiplying `1/n` by `n/n-1` ? I will really appreciate if you can give a brief simple example..

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).